# Regarding HiTop5 IDE from Hitex

Tags: ide, hex, stm32

I have a STM32 Performance stick for developing USB device.
It comes along with HiTop5 IDE for software development and debugging.

I have written programs and flashed into the microcontroller using the IDE.

Now I want to use only the microcontroller and want to load the programs I have written using the IDE to it.

There is a .htp file created to load the project once build is done and .elf created in the objects folder. But there seems to be no hex file created for me to load the program with other methods.

I've searched the net on how to create a hex using this IDE. But didn't find any.

Has anybody used this IDE and know how to generate a hex file from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Project settings in Hitop IDE, in the select the application of the project opened,
click on the general box, Check the create standard code box, it will ask for intel hex or s format, select intel hex option.
Next time you build the project hex file will be generated.